# Solving the Helmholtz equation separably on a conical domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, special-functions, coordinate-systems, eigenfunctions

Suppose that I want to solve the Helmholtz equation,
$$
\bigg[\nabla^2 +k^2\bigg]\psi(\mathbf r)=0
$$
in the three-dimensional conical domain $z>\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, with Dirichlet conditions $\psi(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=0$ on the boundary, and that I want to do this via separation of variables in an orthogonal coordinate system that respects the geometry of my domain. I suspect that this is doable via some form of hyperbolic coordinates where one family of coordinate surfaces are hyperboloids that limit to the cone, and another coordinate is the azimuthal angle about the apex, but I'm having some trouble identifying exactly which coordinate system this is.

So, I want to ask:

- what orthogonal-coordinates system is best suited to this geometry?
- what do the forwards and backwards coordinate transformations look like?
- is the Helmholtz equation separable on this system? if so, what does it look like for each coordinate?
- are the corresponding eigenfunctions known in terms of existing special functions? if so, which ones?
- finally, and if possible, are any vector Helmholtz eigenfunctions known in this geometry?

Answer (score 1):

In spherical coordinates the Laplacian separates as $\Delta=\partial_r^2+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r+\frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{S^2}$, thus you can compute its eigenfunctions in terms of [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) (i.e. the eigenfunctions of $\Delta_{S^2}).$ To satisfy Dirichlet conditions on the boundary of the cone $C$ you are looking for those spherical harmonics which are zero on $C\cap S^2$.

For the vector valued case one can derive a similar expression for the Laplacian (using $\Delta_{S^2}$), but assuming that you have some background on Riemannian geometry, let me show you how your question translates into a well studied setting: Consider $\Omega = C\cap S^2$ as Riemannian manifold with metric $\bar g$ inherited from the sphere, then $\Omega \times (0,\infty)$ with the metric $dr^2+r^2\bar g$ is isometric to $C$. (So far this is just a fancier way to talk about spherical coordinates.) In [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/28a2/d8d290db662d154395e960e44fdeff9fd94b.pdf) (§3) the author gives formulas for the eigenfunctions of the Hodge-Laplacian of spaces with this kind of metric. The Hodge-Laplacian on $1-$forms is dual to the vector valued Laplacian.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a good deal more explicit in the question. My aim is to model an analogue of a Laguerre-Gauss beam reflecting on a conical reflector; that's not separable but I'm OK with something that limits to a plane wave at large z (so hence the hyperboloids). The spherical harmonics are an interesting observation but they just encode too much power radiating at large angles from the cone's axis.

Comment: If I understand you correctly your question boils down to the following: Pull back the euclidean metric via $\mathbb{R}^2\times(0,\infty)\rightarrow C, (x,y,t)\mapsto (x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2+t})$ to get a metric of the form $g_t + \psi(t)dt^2$. Then $X_t=(\mathbb{R}^2,g_t)$ is isometric to one of the hyperbolic layers and the question is, whether we can express its eigenfunctions in terms of special functions?

Comment: To this question however I do not know the answer. I have computed $g_t(x,y)=((2x^2+y^2+t)dx^2+2xy dx\otimes dy + (x^2+2y^2+t)dy^2)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+t}$, which does not separate. Maybe it helps to study $X_t$ with polar coordinates? At least we're one dimension lower now.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of the inhomogeneous polynomial inside the square root, but I guess that that is a relatively minor fix. I'm more concerned by the fact that the $x,y$ parametrization doesn't adapt to $z$, which precludes the fixed-coordinate surfaces from being orthogonal.

Comment: Sorry, the square root should not be there. To also fix the inhomogeneity we now put $\Phi(x,y,t)=(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2+t^2}$. Then $\Phi(\cdot,\cdot,t)$ parametrizes the hyperboloid $\{(x,y,z)\vert ~ x^2+y^2-z^2=-t^2\}$, which then becomes isometric to $(\mathbb{R}^2,g_t)$ with metric $g_t=g_\text{eucl} + (xdx+ydy)^2/(x^2+y^2+t^2)$. Then also $g_t\rightarrow g_{\text{eucl}}$ for $t\rightarrow \infty$, as you wanted.

Comment: By orthogonal coordinates I mean that I'm looking for something that will fit [this formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_coordinates).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70403/discussion-between-jabo-and-e-p).